# Why is the Flux publisher doOnComplete method not being invoked?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-webflux

I try to execute a method after another one is executed by using Flux publisher but the method `doOnComplete` is never invoked.
The code looks like:

```
public class Client implements Serializable {
    private Long id;
    private String category;
    // other properties, getters and setters
}

interface ClientRepository extends JpaRepository<Client,Long> {
    List<Client> findAllByCategory(String category);
    @Transactional
    void deleteByCategory(String category);
}

class ClientResponse {
    private Long status;
    private String message;
}

@Component
class ClientService {
    @Autowired
    ClientRepository clientRepository;
    @Autowired
    WebClient webClient;

  public Mono<ClientResponse> deleteRemoteClient(Long idClient) {
    return webClient.post()
      .uri("/api/remoteClient/{idClient}",idClient)
      .retrieve()
      .bodyToMono(ClientResponse.class)
      .doOnSuccess(ok -> System.out.println(
                          "Delete success for client= " + idClient))
      .doOnError(err -> System.out.println(
                          "Delete failed for client= " + idClient + ", err =" + err));
  }

  /**
   * Get All clients by category, then delete them remotely one by one.
   * When everything goes well, delete all clients locally in one shot by category
   **/
  public Flux<ClientResponse> deleteLocalClientByCategory(String category) {
    return Flux.fromStream(clientRepository.findAllByCategory(category).stream())
      .flatMap(client -> deleteRemoteClient(client.getId()))
      .doOnComplete(() -> clientRepository.deleteByCategory(category));
  }
}

@Component
class ClientHandler {
    @Autowired 
    ClientService service;

    public Mono<ClientResponse> deleteByCatgeory(ServerRequest request) {
        return service.deleteLocalClientByCategory(
                   Long.parseLong(request.queryParam("category").get()))
               .publishNext()
               .flatMap(response -> ServerResponse.ok().build());
    }
}
```

As I mentioned before, the method `deleteRemoteClient(client.getId())` but not `clientRepository.deleteByCategory(category)`.

Comment: where/when is the flux subscribed to?

Comment: @DarrenForsythe You mean the subsribe must be done on deleteRemoteClient(client.getId()) whitch return a Mono?

Comment: I mean the overall chain, where is `deleteLocalClientByCategory` called?

Comment: @DarrenForsythe i updated the post to see where i call the `deleteLocalClientByCategory`

Comment: `JpaRepository` means you are using a blocking database, which in turn means that every database call your do is blocking, and your application might have have poor performance and there's a huge risk of thread starvation during medium loads.

Comment: @ThomasAndolf For the moment i am using Oracle database, but in the future we are going to migrate to MySql Database. But the the moment i have to work a partial reactive stuff :) to complet it soon

Comment: Oracle is blocking and Mysql is blocking too

Answer (score 0):

When you call `publishNext`, you cancel your flux after first element. See illustration [here](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#publishNext--).

So your flux never completes. You should use `doOnCancel` or `doFinally`.

Comment: `doFinally`: onFinally the callback to execute after a terminal signal (complete, error
  * or cancel), this a problem in my case, because i want the method `clientRepository.deleteByCategory(category)` to run right after `deleteRemoteClient(client.getId())` complites successfully, but not if there is an error  !

Answer (score 0):

So, using `.doOnComplite` for that purpose is not good idea, try `.then` operator, example:

```
  ...
  .flatMap(client -> deleteRemoteClient(client.getId()))
  .then(clientRepository.deleteByCategory(category));
```

Comment: `Then` operator must take a `Mono` but the `deleteByCacetgory` is a void method, and the global method must return an object of type `Mono<ClientResponse>`.

Comment: I see your point, but as I said before  clientRepository.deleteByCategory(category) will not work because .doOnComplete() doesn't subscribe on your method

Comment: I'm a little lost with that, is there a way to do this subscribe while keeping the same type of return ?

Comment: As option you can add .subscribe operator .doOnComplete(() -> clientRepository.deleteByCategory(category).subscribe()) it will work, but you can faced with problem if deleteByCacetgory will fail